# how to remove pilcrow sign(¶ ) between tags in html using python

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape the html page by removing required attributes.I am able to remove tags with empty content but stuck with pilcrow sign removal

```
input: `<h2>Tutorial material<a>¶</a></h2>
```

expected output :

```
 <h2>Tutorial material<a></a></h2>
```

code:

```
elements = soup.find_all(True)
 for el in elements:
    if len(el.text) == 0:
        el.extract()
print soup
```

This code removes tags with empty content but i couldnt remove pilcrow sign

`

Comment: `text.replace('¶', '')`

Comment: hi Robin , could you share the working  sample code ..

Comment: You mean like `"<h2>Tutorial material<a>¶</a></h2>".replace('¶', '')`?

Comment: I am using beautiful soup to scrape    elements = soup.find_all(True)     for el in elements:
        if len(k.text) == 0:
            el.extract()
    print soup         this code removes the empty tags with empty content but i couldnt remove the sign with the replace function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

to the beginning of your python file and refer to the pilcrow sign as `u'¶'` when needed.

Answer (score 0):

The code you provided remove empty nodes, you just have to adapt it to include @Robin comment.

One solution is to check if the node text is empty OR is equal to ¶, and remove it:

```
elements = soup.find_all(True)
 for el in elements:
    if len(el.text) == 0 or el.text == u'¶':
        el.extract()
print soup
```

Comment: The use of the `print` keyword suggests he is using Python 2.x. So comparing `el.text` to a unicode character might fail. `u'¶'`should work, though.

Answer (score 0):

Check if the text is (only) the pilcrow:

```py
elements = soup.find_all(True)
for el in elements:
    if len(el.text) == 0 or el.text == u'¶':
        el.extract()
print(soup)
```